# Unable to open Google Chrome on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I am unable to open Google Chrome. I tried removing and installing it again. But this did not solve the problem. On trying this command `google-chrome` on terminal, it shows

```
shm_open() failed: Permission denied
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[8239:8239:0121/203748:ERROR:background_mode_manager_aura.cc(14)] Not implemented reached in virtual void BackgroundModeManager::EnableLaunchOnStartup(bool)
[8239:8239:0121/203748:ERROR:shared_memory_posix.cc(231)] Creating shared memory in /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.et02yU failed: Permission denied
[8239:8239:0121/203748:ERROR:shared_memory_posix.cc(234)] Unable to access(W_OK|X_OK) /dev/shm: Permission denied
[8239:8239:0121/203748:FATAL:shared_memory_posix.cc(236)] This is frequently caused by incorrect permissions on /dev/shm.  Try 'sudo chmod 1777 /dev/shm' to fix.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can anyone help me make Chrome work on my laptop.

Comment: did you get some errors by tring chromium ? or why you must use chrome ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `sudo chmod 1777 /dev/shm` to fix.

btw, it's the last thing that is said in the error output.

Comment: The problem remains every time I login to my system. Can there be a fix to it?

Answer (score 0):

To permanently fix this problem, mount `/dev/shm` with the proper flags, by putting the following in `/etc/fstab`:

```
none  /dev/shm    tmpfs   rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec    0    0
```

The previous change requires a reboot before they get effective.
To get the same effect without reboot, run the following command:

```
sudo mount none -t tmpfs -o rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec /dev/shm
```

If `/dev/shm` was already mounted, add the `remount` option:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec /dev/shm
```

Comment: It gives this error.. "mount: can't find /dev/shm in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab"

Comment: @nomorequestions Have you added `/dev/shm` to `/etc/fstab` as I suggested at the top of the answer?

Comment: I don't get how to do it. Can you please give command to do that. You said to use `sudo mount -o rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec /dev/shm` is it to add `/dev/shm` to `/etc/fstab`? If so it gives the error as I mentioned previously.

Comment: @nomorequestions Example: `sudo nano /etc/fstab` (or `vim`, or whatever favorite editor that you trust with root privileges). Then put the line from my answer in it and reboot.

Comment: I added the line `none  /dev/shm    tmpfs   rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec    0    0` into `/etc/fstab` and rebooted.. But it did not solve the problem.

Comment: @nomorequestions What does `stat /dev/shm` output?

Comment: `File: ‘/dev/shm/’  
  Size: 40         Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory  
Device: 5h/5d Inode: 10995       Links: 2  
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)  
Access: 2015-02-04 19:29:28.030285953 +0530  
Modify: 2015-02-04 19:29:21.714286235 +0530  
Change: 2015-02-04 19:29:21.714286235 +0530  
 Birth: -`

Comment: @nomorequestions If the permissions don't survive a reboot, try adding `mode=1777` to the line in fstab, as in `none  /dev/shm    tmpfs   rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777    0    0`

Comment: Done. But still doesn't work. `stat /dev/shm` has only one value changed other than time and dates, inode value is now `13324`.

Comment: That's weird. Do you have any startup scripts or udev rules (in `/lib/udev/rules.d/`) that affects `/dev/shm`?

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu 14.04) I have `/dev/shm` as a symlink to `/run/shm`.
I also have `/run/shm` mounted with this options. 
`none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0`. I believe that it should be monted without `noexec` option. NativeClient and OpenGL applications may require this
It's strange, but I can not find a script that mounts `/run/shm` for me. It's surely _not_ in `/etc/fstab`